# Port forwarding on all ports except ssh on macOS Sierra (redsocks)

Tags: macos, firewall

I am trying to forward all ports except port 22 on OSX Sierra using pfctl but it doesn't seem to work.

file: /pf.conf

```
ext_if = "inet"
rdr pass $ext_if proto tcp from any to any -> 127.0.0.1 port 12345
rdr pass $ext_if proto udp from any to any -> 127.0.0.1 port 10053
pass out proto tcp from any to any port ssh
```

I enabled it with

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
sudo pfctl -f pf.conf
sudo pfctl -e
```

The traffic seems to be redirecting fine to port 12345, but I can't get port 22 to passthrough.

Answer (score 1):

The ssh line should be above the ‘rdr’ lines, so that the ssh line is matched first.